# Why isn't my count going up with my while statement php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a table named "records" and I have a column named "gender" with values of "M" and "F". I would like to tally the number of males and females and echo them onto my html document but I keep getting 0 as my output.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM records";
   if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
      $genderM = 0;
      $genderF = 0;

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         $gender = $row['gender'] . "<br> \n";
               
         if ($gender == 'M') {
             echo "TRUE <br> \n";                  
             $genderM++;
         }
         if ($gender == 'F') {
             $genderF++;
         }
         else {
             echo '';
         }
     }
     echo $genderM . '<br>';
     echo $genderF . '<br>';
 } 
 mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You are adding “<br>” to $gender variable then checking if the variable equals to M or F which will never be the case! Instead you might check $row[‘gender’]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has better option to recieve desirable result for you - `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `records` WHERE `gender` = M");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo 'COUNT GENDER M : ', $row[0];
```

And then do the same for `F` gender.

As you can see - no need to make `while` loop an handle each row with counter.

Have a look at official doc https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 3):

You are adding `"<br> \n"` to `$gender` so the comparison does not work.

You might be better off checking `$row['gender']` instead, ie

```
if ($row['gender'] == 'M') {
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php) function to make things alot cleaner.

```
$array = {"F", "M", "F"}
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

output:

```
Array
(
 [F] => 2
 [M] => 1
)
```